# DataWeave functions fail when moved to a module

Tags: module, dataweave

I'm having trouble moving functions to a custom Module file.

Using Anypoint Studio v7.11.1. I have this code that works in a Transform Message component:

```
%dw 2.0
output application/json


var flights = {
  "flights": [
    {
      "airlineName": "Delta",
      "availableSeats": 40,
      "departureDate": "Apr 11, 2018",
      "destination": "LAX",
      "flightCode": "A134DS",
      "origination": "MUA",
      "planeType": "BOEING 777",
      "price": "750.00"
    },
    {
      "airlineName": "Delta",
      "availableSeats": 18,
      "departureDate": "Aug 11, 2018",
      "destination": "LAX",
      "flightCode": "A1QWER",
      "origination": "MUA",
      "planeType": "BOEING 747",
      "price": "496.00"
    },
    {
      "airlineName": "Delta",
      "availableSeats": 10,
      "departureDate": "Feb 11, 2018",
      "destination": "LAX",
      "flightCode": "A1B2C4",
      "origination": "MUA",
      "planeType": "BOEING 737",
      "price": "199.99"
    },
    {
      "flightCode": "rree0001",
      "availableSeats": 0,
      "destination": "LAX",
      "planeType": "Boeing 787",
      "price": 541.0,
      "origination": "MUA",
      "departureDate": "2016-01-20T00:00:00",
      "airlineName": "american"
    },
    {
      "flightCode": "ffee0192",
      "availableSeats": 0,
      "destination": "LAX",
      "planeType": "Boeing 777",
      "price": 300.0,
      "origination": "MUA",
      "departureDate": "2016-01-20T00:00:00",
      "airlineName": "american"
    },
    {
      "flightCode": "eefd4511",
      "availableSeats": 100,
      "destination": "LAX",
      "planeType": "Boeing 777",
      "price": 900.0,
      "origination": "MUA",
      "departureDate": "2016-01-15T00:00:00",
      "airlineName": "american"
    },
    {
      "airlineName": "United",
      "availableSeats": 52,
      "departureDate": "2015/02/11",
      "destination": "LAX",
      "flightCode": "ER45if",
      "origination": "MUA",
      "planeType": "Boeing 737",
      "price": 345.99
    },
    {
      "airlineName": "United",
      "availableSeats": 12,
      "departureDate": "2015/04/11",
      "destination": "LAX",
      "flightCode": "ER45jd",
      "origination": "MUA",
      "planeType": "Boeing 777",
      "price": 346
    },
    {
      "airlineName": "United",
      "availableSeats": 0,
      "departureDate": "2015/06/11",
      "destination": "LAX",
      "flightCode": "ER0945",
      "origination": "MUA",
      "planeType": "Boeing 707",
      "price": 423
    }
  ]
}


import dw::modules::FlightsLibSolution

var keysToDelete = ["openFlightsAirportId", "type", "source"]

//var flights = readUrl("classpath://examples/flightsToLAX.json")

var airportDetailsByIATA = readUrl("classpath://airportInfoTiny.csv", "application/csv") groupBy $.IATA

fun joinAirportDetailsV2(payload :Object, keysToDelete = [], groupedAirportDetails = []) =
flights:{( 
    payload.flights map ( (flight) -> flight:
    //join in the destination airport details with mapObject
    flight mapObject (value, key, index) ->
        if( lower(key) ~= "destination") 
            destination: groupedAirportDetails[ flight.destination ][0] 
                        -- keysToDelete
                
                //{(
                    //airportDetails[ ?($.IATA == flight.destination)]
                    //groupedAirportDetails[ flight.destination ]
                //)}
        else (key): value
    )

)}

---
joinAirportDetailsV2(flights, keysToDelete,  airportDetailsByIATA )
```

But when I move the function to the dw.modules.FlightsLibSolution.dwl file and I call

```
---
dw::modules::FlightsLibSolution::joinAirportDetailsV2(flights, keysToDelete,  airportDetailsByIATA )
```

I get the error:

```
"Too many arguments (3) for function with parameters (payload, keysToDelete).

128| dw::modules::FlightsLibSolution::joinAirportDetailsV2(flights, keysToDelete,  airportDetailsByIATA )
     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

But if I call this function instead in a module

```
fun joinAirportDetailsV1(payload :Object,keysToDelete = [], groupedAirportDetails = []) = 

flights:
{( 
payload.flights map  ( (flight) -> 
    flight:
    flight - "destination"
    
    //join in the destination airport details with ++
    ++ destination: 
        //{( 
            groupedAirportDetails[ flight.destination ][0] 
            
        //)} 
        //- "openFlightsAirportId" - "type" - "source" 
        -- keysToDelete

    
) 

)}
```

It works.

Also, if I put this function in the Module:

```
fun joinAirportDetailsV3(payload :Object ) =
flights:{( 
    payload.flights map ( (flight) -> flight:
    //join in the destination airport details with mapObject
    flight mapObject (value, key, index) ->
        if( lower(key) ~= "destination") 
            destination: groupedAirportDetails[ flight.destination ][0] 
                        -- keysToDelete
                
                //{(
                    //airportDetails[ ?($.IATA == flight.destination)]
                    //groupedAirportDetails[ flight.destination ]
                //)}
        else (key): value
    )

)}
```

and then I define the two variables used in the function in my Transform Message component:

```
import dw::modules::FlightsLibSolution

var keysToDelete = ["openFlightsAirportId", "type", "source"]

var airportDetailsByIATA = readUrl("classpath://airportInfoTiny.csv", "application/csv") groupBy $.IATA

var groupedAirportDetails = airportDetailsByIATA

var flights = ...

---
FlightsLibSolution::joinAirportDetailsV3(flights)
```

I get the error:

````
output application/json



var flights = {
  "flights": [
    {
     ...'. Reason: Unable to resolve reference of: `groupedAirportDetails`.```

Why isn't the `groupedAirportDetails` variable resolved? This is not just a Preview pane error. I get the same error raised then I run the Mule app.
````

Answer (score 0):

The syntax to import a functions is:

```
import joinAirportDetailsV3 from dw::modules::FlightsLibSolution
```

For that to work there has to be file named FlightLibSolution.dwl in the src/main/resources/dw/modules directory.

Alternatively, you can import all functions from the module like this:

```
import * from dw::modules::FlightLibSolution
```

Comment: So a variable referenced in a module but not defined in the module still must be imported? Why don't my local versions of the variables override variables defined in the module?

Comment: The joinAirportDetailsV3 function is being imported. The error is from the internal variable groupedAirportDetails, that I defined in the Transform Message component, not in the Module. Shouldn't I be able to define variables referenced inside a function implementation in my code, not hardcoded in the Module? I know a work around is to add parameters to the function call, so then they will be passed into the function call.

Comment: The functions in the module don't know about the variables in the Transform Operator. The only option is to explicitly use parameters.